# Why doesn't this cast generate a compiler warning?

Tags: java, casting, compiler-warnings, runtime-error

Why doesn't the following java code generate a compiler warning saying something like "Unsafe cast from SuperClass to SomeBaseClass"?

```
public abstract SuperClass
{
    static SuperClass create()
    {
        return new AnotherBaseClass();
    }

    private static class SomeBaseClass extends SuperClass
    {
        void print()
        {
            System.out.println("Hello World");
        }
    }

    private static class AnotherBaseClass extends SuperClass
    {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SomeBaseClass actuallyAnotherClass = (SomeBaseClass)SuperClass.create();
        actuallyAnotherClass.print();
    }
}
```

I used jdk1.6.0_25/bin/javac on a Windows machine. Eclipse Helios doesn't warn about it either.

Instead it results in a runtime exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: SuperClass$AnotherBaseClass cannot be cast to SuperClass$SomeBaseClass

Comment: Looks like the print() function is part of SomeBaseClass, not AnotherBaseClass.  I believe the error should be on the actuallyAnotherClass.print(); line.

Comment: But on the actuallyAnotherClass.print(); line I know it's of the correct type because I've casted it on the line before. The questioning is about why (SomeBaseClass)SuperClass.create(); is allowed to convert AnotherBaseClass to SomeBaseClass without checking the type first.

Comment: I think that might be because static SuperClass create() is returning a SuperClass type.  You can cast between SuperClass and AnotherBaseClass.  You can also cast between SuperClass and SomeBaseClass.  But you can't cast between AnotherBaseClass and SomeBaseClass.  If you change the return type of create() to AnotherBaseClass, I don't think it will compile.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but as I prefer to return the type highest up in the type hierarchy I would rather have a compile time warning about the unsafe cast than encountering a ClassCastException during runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the compiler would throw an error if the cast was not possible at all, e.g. if the `create()` methods return type would be `AnotherBaseClass` instead of `SuperClass`.

Since it returns a `SuperClass` the compiler doesn't know what will actually be returned - it could as well return a `SomeBaseClass`. Thus it has to trust that you know what you do with that cast.

*Edit*:

To get a warning when casting you might try and employ a code analysis tool like [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/).
Note, however, that those tools most likely can't or don't check the class hierarchy and thus might only be able to warn about (non-primitive) casts being used in general. Thus if you use a library that requires casts (e.g. if you're using apache commons collections which doesn't support generics yet) you'd get a *lot* of warnings.

After all, programming is still an *art* and you still need to know what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, so it doesn't know what's returned. Couldn't the compiler require the programmer to check what's returned or else generate an "unsafe cast" warning? I.e to use an instanceof check.

Even if it isn't desirable in all cases, I for one would like at least an opt-in when compiling to generate such warnings.

Comment: @jontejj well, the compiler still trusts the programmer and you shouldn't do things like this. True you should do an `instanceof` if you're not sure what is being returned but there might be cases where that would be overkill. AFAIK there's also no option to make the compiler complain about those casts. It's also a legacy issue since before generics casting from `Object` to anything else often was the only solution (you wouldn't want to add an `instanceof` to all those casts in some pre-Java 5 code, would you?). What might help you here is using a code checker. I'll update my anwer.

Comment: I accept your answer although I would have liked having the option without having to resort to checkstyles. Atleast you presented me with a constructive way forward. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Javac only warns for unsafe casts when using generics. Here the compiler trusts you to know what you're doing :)

Comment: I find trust to be troublesome in enough cases to wonder if having such a naive compiler is a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

That's not a compiler warning. It has failed at runtime while trying to cast `AnotherBaseClass` object to `SomeBaseClass`.

Comment: This is not very helpful as I state this in the question. The question was "why not?" and not "what's this?".